# How do you calculate the modulo of a really high number with a large power, with a really high mod number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to work out $516489222^{22} \pmod{96899}$. I know there are easier ways of working this out, but am really struggling.

Answer (score 10):

Note that $516489222 \equiv 17552 \pmod{96899}$. This gives

$$ 516489222^{22} \equiv 17552^{22} \pmod{96899}.$$

Now it is easy to calculate

\begin{align*}
17552^{2^{1}} &\equiv 30783 \pmod{96899}\\
17552^{2^{2}} &\equiv 30783^{2} \equiv 17768 \pmod{96899}\\
17552^{2^{3}} &\equiv 17768^{2} \equiv 4882 \pmod{96899}\\
17552^{2^{4}} &\equiv 4882 ^{2} \equiv 93669 \pmod{96899}.
\end{align*}

Since $22 = 2^{4} + 2^{2} + 2^{1},$ it follows that

\begin{align*}
17552^{22}
&\equiv 17552^{2^{4}} \cdot 17552^{2^{2}} \cdot 17552^{2^{1}} \pmod{96899} \\
&\equiv 93669 \cdot 17768 \cdot 30783 \pmod{96899} \\
&\equiv 4647 \pmod{96899}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 7):

*Here's a somewhat high-level description of the several tricks one can use to make numbers smaller and computations "easier". You may need some knowledge of elementary number theory to understand these tricks.*

Things can be made easier by first factoring $96899 = 11 \cdot 23 \cdot 383$. Then, to find $$516489222^{22} \pmod{96899},$$ it suffices to find 
$$\begin{align} &516489222^{22} \pmod{11}, \tag{1.} \\ &516489222^{22} \pmod{23}, \tag{2.} \\ &516489222^{22} \pmod{383}, \tag{3.} \end{align}$$
and then combine the results using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). For each of these three cases, we will use the fact that for all $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod{m}$, we have
$$a^b \equiv (a \mod m)^{(b \mod \phi(m))} \pmod m,$$ 
to reduce the numbers in the computations considerably. Here $\phi$ is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), and being able to reduce exponents with multiples of $\phi(m)$ is a consequence of [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem). (In our applications $m$ is always prime, in which case the theorem is also known as [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), where $\phi(p) = p-1$.)

1. For the first, using that $516489222 \equiv -4 \pmod{11}$ and $22 \equiv 2 \pmod{\phi(11)}$,
   we get 
   $$516489222^{22} \equiv (-4)^2 \equiv 16 \equiv 5 \pmod{11}.$$
2. For the second, using that $516489222 \equiv 3 \ [\not\equiv 0] \pmod{23}$ and $22 \equiv 0 \pmod{\phi(23)}$, we get
   $$516489222^{22} \equiv 3^0 \equiv 1 \pmod{23}.$$
3. For the last, using that $516489222 \equiv -66 \pmod{383}$, we get
   $$516489222^{22} \equiv (-66)^{22} \pmod{383}.$$
   We do not get around doing some modular computations here, but the work can be reduced a bit by using [square-and-multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring): 
   $$516489222^{22} \equiv (-66)^{22} \equiv ((-66)^2)^{11} \equiv 143^{11} \equiv 143 \cdot (143^2)^5 \equiv 143 \cdot 150^5 \\ \equiv 143 \cdot 150 \cdot (150^2)^2 \equiv 2 \cdot (-97)^2 \equiv 2 \cdot 217 \equiv 51 \pmod{383}.$$

So concluding, we have 
$$516489222^{22} \equiv \begin{cases} 5 \pmod{11} \\ 1 \pmod{23} \\ 51 \pmod{383} \end{cases}$$
Combining them using the CRT, we get
$$516489222^{22} \equiv 4647 \pmod{11 \cdot 23 \cdot 383 = 96899}$$

Comment: One thing you've omitted: $x^{22} = 1 \bmod 23$ requires $x \neq 0 \bmod 23$ which you didn't (explicitly) check.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: note that this work best is the modulo number is the composite of many small primes, if it is prime itself this won't work

Answer (score 3):

The useful property is $$(x\mod{n})(y\mod{n})\equiv(xy \mod{n})$$ If you iterate this, it works for integer powers too.  That means that the OP is equal to $$(616489222 \mod{96899})^{22}\pmod{96899}\equiv 17552^{22}\pmod{96899}$$

We can use the property again, noting that $(x^2)^{11}\pmod{n}\equiv (x^2\mod{n})^{11}\pmod{n}$.  Hence $$17522^{22}\pmod{96899}\equiv (17522^2\mod{96899})^{11}\pmod{96899}\equiv44452^{11}\pmod{96899}$$

A few more steps like this and you'll be done.  This process can be made quicker by using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), which can handle unwieldy arithmetic, including the OP in one step.

Answer (score 2):

The Chinese Remainder Theorem can be helpful in this situation. Since 
$96899=11*23*383$ it suffices to calculate the number $\pmod{11}, \pmod{23}$ and $\pmod{383}$.

$516489222 \equiv 7 \pmod{11}$. By Fermat Little Theorem

$$(516489222)^{22} \equiv ((516489222)^{10})^27^2 \equiv 1 \cdot 7^2 \equiv 5 \pmod {11}$$

$516489222 \equiv 3 \pmod{23}$. By Fermat Little Theorem

$$(516489222)^{22} \equiv  1 \pmod {23}$$

$516489222 \equiv 317 \equiv -66 \pmod{383}$. Then

$$(516489222)^{22} \equiv (-66)^{22} \equiv  (143)^{11} \pmod {383}$$

Now

$$(143)^{2} \equiv 150 \pmod {383}$$
$$(143)^{4} \equiv 150^2 \equiv -97 \pmod {383}$$
$$(143)^{8} \equiv (-97)^2 \equiv 217 \pmod {383}$$
$$(143)^{11} \equiv (143)^{8} (143)^{2} 143 \equiv 217 \cdot 150 \cdot 143 \equiv -5 \cdot 143 \equiv 51 \pmod {383}$$

Now, you can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find the unique class $\pmod{96899}$ which is $7 \pmod{11}, 1 \pmod{23}$ and $51 \pmod{383}$